# Kettle transformations locks database tables?

Tags: oracle, pentaho, kettle

I have a main transformation calling a couple of sub transformation using a single threader step in Pentaho Kettle. The sub transformations write to an Oracle database.

The main transformation looks like this:

```
Data Frame --> Single threader 1  --> Single threader 1 --> Single threader 3
```

The sub transformations called by the single threaders look like this:

```
In --> A bunch of modifications and checks --> Write to DB
 |
 v
Out
```

The reason that the out step is directly connected to the in step is that I want to return the row unmodified, but I need to modify it to get the right data to insert into the DB. Each sub transformation update one or two tables.

All the steps in all the transformations use the same database connection, that is a shared resource between the files. The "Make transformation database transactional" checkbox is checked in all transformations.

My problem is this: When I run the main transform, a number of the tables are not updated even though there are no error messages. Those tables also remain locked after the transformation has finished, and remain locked until I quit Spoon. What tables are affected by this might change from time to time - sometimes there are many, sometimes just one, sometimes none. I have not been able to detect any pattern.

Am I doing something wrong? What can I do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Kettle doesn't have advanced database transaction management abilities (community editition doen't have even "Make transformation database transactional"). 
It's really hard to break into small pieces whole data processing on small transactions scope. Why don't you prepare and move all data into database temp tables and then, on database level,
move data around using internal database transactions in order u need.

Comment: @simar Thanks for the comment. I think the community edition do have the transactional option, since I am running it. Your suggestion about moving the data into temp table and then let the DBMS take care of it is interesting, I will look into it. Thanks!